# Calculus/Analysis, show they are equal

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Prove that for each $x\geq 0$
$$\int_0^x \left(\int_0^t f(s)\,ds\right)\,dt=\int_0^x(x-s)\,f(s)\,ds$$
I think it's something related to change of variables, right? I think what I should do is proving 
$\int_0^t f(s)ds$ can change to $(x-s)f(s)ds$ by change a variable? However, I don't see how can I change a variable and prove this. Anyone can help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** By Change of order of integration note that:

$$\int_0^x (\int_0^t f(s)\,ds)\,dt=\int_0^x (\int_s^x f(s)\,dt)\,ds$$

Hence we are done.

Comment: Can you explain more? I don't see why they are equal.

Comment: @Kelan Draw the domain of integration in $s,t$ plane and change the order of integration.

Comment: I see it now. Thanks!

Comment: @Kelan You're welcome.